# retaining the final postion after rotation css3 animation

Tags: javascript, css

is there a way to make this css3 javascript animation smooth and fine please see the link[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8Tuy/38/)

css animation i use is given below

```
.pageanim
{
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation:nextpage 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;


}
.hideface
{
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;

}
@-webkit-keyframes nextpage /*Safari and Chrome*/
{
from {-webkit-transform:rotatey(0deg); }
to {-webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg);
}

}


.revpageanim
{
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation:prepage 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0% 0px;

}

@-webkit-keyframes prepage 
{
from {-webkit-transform:rotatey(0deg);}
to {-webkit-transform:rotatey(90deg);}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the animation-fill-mode property, you can choose whether it is the first or last frame of the animation that should be kept at the end of the animation:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: please look the java script am making the left to 0% after animation ends.thats what it stops there.